# how to remove first word from a php string

Tags: php, split, text-segmentation

I'd like to remove the first word from a string using PHP.
Tried searching but couldn't find an answer that I could make sense of.

eg: "White Tank Top" so it becomes "Tank Top"

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the characters before the first space?

Answer (score 66):

No need for explode or array manipulation, you can use function [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
echo strstr("White Tank Top"," ");
//Tank Top
```

UPDATE: Thanks to @Sid To remove the extra white space you can do:

```
echo substr(strstr("White Tank Top"," "), 1);
```

Comment: This is better than the array manipulation answers, however this will leave the space character too. This can be cut out by doing echo substr(strstr("White Tank Top"," "), 1);

Comment: +1 for simplicity, I keep forgetting about `strtr`. Was about to type out 3 lines using `strpos` + `substr` when I saw your answer. Add an `ltrim` in case there are multiple spaces and you're golden.

Comment: @Sid white space at the beginning you mean? i just gave it a check and it worked fine for me can you verify?

Comment: @Fanis i totally get you, with so many different functions for string manipulation in php is easy to forget.

Comment: @amosrivera like @Sid said it will include the space it's matching on. You won't see it easily by echoing out on a web page but do a `strlen` or run it in a debugger and you'll spot it :)

Comment: @Sid @Fanis `strlen` showed the white space interesting, added your solution to the answer thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `preg_replace` function with the regex `^(\w+\s)` that will match the first word of a string per se:

```
$str = "White Tank Top";
$str = preg_replace("/^(\w+\s)/", "", $str);
var_dump($str); // -> string(8) "Tank Top"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function remove_word($sentence)
{
 $words=array_shift(explode(' ', $sentence));
 return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

?

Comment: could you also condense that down into `return implode(' ', array_shift(explode(' ', $sentence)));`? i was never quite sure with php.

Comment: This solution is a memory hog. If the string has lots of spaces the arrays will become large. amosrivera's solution is much better (though not quite complete as it leaves the space character too).

Comment: @Patrick Perini: no - array_shift() returns the first element in the array - not the modified array

Comment: @Sid: first, amosrivera's answer is semantically different (consider what happens with a string containing no spaces) also I would hardly call this a memory hog - I would expect it to use more memory than amosrivera's answer - but without testing each method I can't tell which has a bigger effective footprint on the system.

Comment: Hog or not, this answer is missing an explanation.  The point is, your snippet performs too many explosions.  Please see my limited explosion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'White Tank Top';

$split = explode(' ', $string);
if (count($split) === 1) {
    // do you still want to drop the first word even if string only contains 1 word?
    // also string might be empty
} else {
    // remove first word
    unset($split[0]);
    print(implode(' ', $split));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_word($sentence)
{
    $exp = explode(' ', $sentence);
    $removed_words = array_shift($exp);
    if(count($exp)>1){
        $w = implode(' ', $exp);
    }else{
        $w = $exp[0];
    }
    return $w;
}
```

Try this function i hope it's work for you .

Answer (score -3):

If you are not guaranteed to have a space in your string, be careful to choose a technique that won't fail on such cases.

If using `explode()` be sure to limit the explosions for best efficiency.

[Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/b46CI):

```
$strings = ["White", "White Tank", "White Tank Top"];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo "\n{$string}:";
    echo "\n-\t" , substr($string, 1 + (strpos($string, ' ') ?: -1));

    $explodeOnce = explode(' ', $string, 2);
    echo "\n-\t" , end($explodeOnce);              

    echo "\n-\t" , substr(strstr($string, " "), 1);

    echo "\n-\t" , ltrim(strstr($string, " "));

    echo "\n-\t" , preg_replace('~^\S+\s~', '', $string);
}
```

Output:

```
White:
-   White
-   White
-                       // strstr() returned false
-                       // strstr() returned false  
-   White
White Tank:
-   Tank
-   Tank
-   Tank
-   Tank
-   Tank
White Tank Top:
-   Tank Top
-   Tank Top
-   Tank Top
-   Tank Top
-   Tank Top
```

My preference is the regex technique because it is stable in all cases above and is a single function call.  Note that there is no need for a capture group because the fullstring match is being replaced. `^` matches the start of the string, `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters and `\s` matches one whitespace character.